# First difference estimator inconsistent

Tags: time-series, differences, exogeneity

This is a simple issue but I seem to need some illustration . If I have a first difference model as in :
$$ y_{it}-y_{it-1} = (X_{it}- X_{it-1})'\beta + (U_{it}- U_{it-1}) \ \ t=2,..T$$
which I am using in order to get rid of time-invariant unobserved individual effects. I don't understand:

1. How can it be that $cov(U_{it-1}, X_{it})\neq 0$ ?
   For T=3 we would have:
   $$ y_{i2}-y_{i1} = (X_{i2}- X_{i1})'\beta + (U_{i2}- U_{i1})\equiv y_{i1}* = X_{i1}*'\beta + U_{i1}* $$
   $$ y_{i3}-y_{i2} = (X_{i3}- X_{i2})'\beta + (U_{i3}- U_{i2})\equiv y_{i2}* = X_{i2}*'\beta + U_{i2}* $$
   Then, why would the covariance between $U_{i1}$ and  $X_{i2}$ be non-zero and conversely for the case of $U_{i2}$ and  $X_{i3}$?
2. Given that the latter is the case, why is $\hat{\beta}_{fdiff}$ inconsistent?